# Android v7 Toolbar button alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I added `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in my app using below code, now I want to show a button in the right end of the toolbar, but not able to do so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/accent_color"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/showevents"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="UPCOMING \nEVENTS"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I have added the below shown too but its not getting moved to right.

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

**Attached image for reference:**

[image]

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You should add `android:layout_gravity="end"` for your Button :

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/showevents"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="UPCOMING \nEVENTS"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Better set the style of the button to `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"` or use `background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` instead of a @null background to have a ripple effect when touched otherwise the button seems disabled.

Comment: Tip: `android:textAllCaps="true"` could be used instead of writing all caps `android:text` yourself. Material themed buttons automatically include it, but on older devices it's normal to have non-uppercase buttons.

Comment: @Roel, `?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` to have them both.

Comment: Use "end" instead of "right" (That's what Android Studio is warning me in 2018)

Comment: What if I add one view programmatically, In my case View v1 = inflate(R.layout.view1); v1.addRule(ALIGN_END, TURE); getToolbar().addView(v1);  does not work. please help, thx.

Answer (score 9):

Or for image on the top right:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:title="Edit Note">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/submitEditNote"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Your way is right but take a look at official doc: ([Resourcs](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html#kotlin))

**Create menu of items:**

```
<!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
    android:title="@string/action_favorite"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

**Add menu action by ID**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
            return true;

        case R.id.action_favorite:
            // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
            // as a favorite...
            return true;

        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```